# Jquery animate replaceWith so it fades in

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like the 'Answer' text to fade in.

```
<div id="div1" style="cursor: pointer;">Reveal</div>
<script>
$("#div1").click(function () {
$('#div1').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $(this).replaceWith("<span>ANSWER HERE</span>" ); });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unclear. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and give us some context and what the problem is with that code.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected my answer now please check this out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).text("finaly it answered .................");
    $(this).fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="cursor: pointer;">Reveal</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the reply but this wasn't my issue. I actually wanted the ANSWER HERE text to fade in instead of simply appearing. The double quotes was misleading, have amended in question. @user2172737

Comment: Ok got it any ways you have an answer below

Comment: Thanks but the ANSWER HERE text still doesn't fade.

Comment: Just give an answer for it please check

Comment: Let me know if this has helped you

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

Html:

```
<div id="div1">Reveal</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#div1").click(function () {
$('#div1').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $(this).replaceWith("<span>ANSWER HERE</span>" ); });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hfqo8p2j/)

**OR**

UPDATED FIDDLE FILE HERE [**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hfqo8p2j/4/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but this seems to be the same as my my code?

I wanted the 'ANSWER HERE' text to fade in, not appear suddenly

Comment: ya ok wait sir @TomMJ

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me

Comment: My pleasure sir @TomMJ

Comment: Thanks but the ANSWER HERE text still doesn't fade.